# csh color prompt via eval

Tags: eval, alias, command-prompt, csh

My goal is to set a prompt in csh shell via eval.

I've created a tcl script that prints a command (in real life it does much more):

```
puts "set prompt=\"%m %{\\033\[1;31m%}red prompt%{\\033\[0m%} %~ >\""
```

Then, in csh, I defined an alias:

```csh
alias red_prompt 'eval `/usr/bin/tclsh test_prompt.tcl`'
```

When I use that alias, I get an error:

```
> red_prompt
Missing ].
```

I tried playing with backslashes but it did not help.

How I can make it working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an external command; you can use `%{...%}` to output escape sequences:

```
set prompt = '%{\033[1;31m%}RED%{\033[0m%}%% '
```

Relevant manpage entry:

```
%{string%}
    Includes string as a literal escape sequence.  It should be
    used only to change terminal attributes and should not move
    the cursor location.  This cannot be the last sequence in
    prompt.
```

There are also some shortcuts for standout, bold, and underline (but not colours):

```
%S (%s)
    Start (stop) standout mode.
%B (%b)
    Start (stop) boldfacing mode.
%U (%u)
    Start (stop) underline mode.
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, I have the TCL script to do much more. And setting the prompt is one of the steps.

Comment: What exactly is "much more" @Michael? There may be better ways to solve that, too.

Comment: The usual trick is to hook in to the special `cwdcmd`, `precmd`, and/or `postcmd` aliases by the way and source a tcsh script from there. E.g. [like this](https://github.com/arp242/dotfiles/blob/master/_old/tcsh/tcsh/aliases.tcsh#L4), which sources [this](https://github.com/arp242/dotfiles/blob/master/_old/tcsh/tcsh/cwdcmd.tcsh).

Comment: My tcl scripts generates multiple setenv and other commands which are then executed by the `eval`. You can think of this script as similar to the "module".

Comment: I suspect it's just an issue with the backslashes @Michael; I don't really know tcl, but probably remove the \ in front of `\[`? Or maybe add more of them? Or maybe some other \ somewhere – mixing these kind of things is always tricky as you're escaping in two contexts. I suggest starting with a simple prompt and building from there, adding one element at a time.

Comment: The problem is not with tcl but with the `eval`. It does not like the `[` in any form.

Comment: It's probably a quoting/escaping issue though @Michael; quoting escaping is super tricky in csh. This is why you generally source stuff from an alias that's more complex than adding a few flags and the like (or use a better shell if you have the option). I forgot the exact caveats and I don't really have the time to test/figure all of this out, but I'd look in this direction.